# Avoid 502 error/timeout when running Python script on server

Tags: python, html, server

I have a very basic web application that has a button that will run a Python script in the background. This script pulls in a lot of data and takes close to 3 hours to complete sometimes (which is normal and totally fine). What I want to do is have the user click the button and start the script in the background then redirect them to the home page. I don't think that my web form or Python script is important to show, but here's the "middle" page that should be doing what I want. However, it just tries to run the script and eventually times out and says "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." Any help would be much appreciated!

Updated code suggestion from Serge:

```
import os
import sys

load_path='/var/www/cgi-bin/resourcedb/scripts/'
sys.path.append(load_path)
os.system("nohup python " + load_path + "upload_rg_test.py &")
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head>"
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/">'
print "</head></html>"
```

Comment: are you open to a different solution that what you have tried, like celery?

Comment: Actually, you may have just given me a different idea. I'll update soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This scripts does not seem to return a correct HTTP response : header declares a text/html content, and body in not a correct HTML page. I would use :

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head>"
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://webdesign.about.com/">'
print "</head></html>"
```

Comment: I tried that (see updated code above) but still had the same error.

Comment: @KeatonAdams My intent was to replace the script not to add that before. But could you use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) or any other network spy to see exactly what your scripts sends to the browser ?

Comment: I tried removing my window.location change and just using your code, but still had the same problem. I will try using wireshark. Thanks!

Comment: @KeatonAdams : BTW, I'm not used to Python for web servers, but did you try to use `\r\n` instead of simply `\n` ?

Comment: Still didn't have any luck.